# Problema al ver si existen IDs en un archivo CSV con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Estoy leyendo un archivo CSV y recorriéndolo con PHP. Ahí no hay ningún problema. La cosa es que quiero ver si sacando los ids de una tabla de una BBDD MySQL con PHP, si me permite ver qué Ids hay en un fichero csv y cuáles no, así como meter los que no en un array para luego trabajar con ellos. He aquí el código:

```
require_once "connection-mysql.php";

//Tengo que coger los eam de MySQL y recorrer MySQL para sacar todos los eam

$archivo=fopen("articulos.csv", "r");
$datosCSV="";
$eam=0;
$encontrado=false;
$idNoEncontrados=array();


//SACO LOS DATOS DEL MYSQL PARA PREPARAR MI ARRAY DE BÚSQUEDA
$queryMySQL="SELECT * FROM articulos";
$lecturaMySQL=mysqli_query($conWebService,$queryMySQL);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($lecturaMySQL)){
        $datosMySQL[]=$row;
    }
    
    // echo "<pre>"; 
    // var_dump($datosMySQL);
    // echo "</pre>";
    $arrayMySQLId=array();

    foreach ($datosMySQL as $key=>$value) { //Con esto ya tengo un array con todos los IdPedidos del MySQL
        $arrayMySQLId[]=$value['eam'];
    }

    

foreach ($arrayMySQLId as $key => $value) {

    $eam=$value; //esto está correcto
    // echo $eam;

    while(!feof($archivo)){

        $datosCSV=fgetcsv($archivo); //ESTO ESTÁ CORRECTO

            //LOS PROBLEMAS EMPIEZAN POR AQUÍ

            foreach ($datosCSV as $key=>$value) {
                // echo "<pre>";
                // var_dump($datosCSV);
                // echo "</pre>";


                if($eam==$value){
                    // $encontrado=true;
                    echo "El eam del artículo ".$eam." existe en nuestro CSV";
                } else {
                    $idNoEncontrados[]=$eam;
                    // echo "<pre>";
                    // var_dump($idNoEncontrados);
                    // echo "</pre>";
                }
            }
    }
}
    



fclose($archivo);
```

Lo que me tendría que mostrar en el array de idNoEncontrados es el valor 2, 4 y 5; que son los valores de MySQL que no están en el CSV. Sin embargo, lo que me muestra es lo siguiente:

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [7]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

No comprendo por qué me devuelve el valor de 1 en todos, entiendo que 1 es true, pero no comprendo por qué me sale este resultado ni en qué estoy fallando.
Creo que los tiros pueden ir (es lo único raro que he encontrado) en que el documento CSV que lee me lo muestra así:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "eam;nombre"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "1;" "
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(40) "RELOJ DEPORTIVO CON GPS GARMIN FENIX 5S""
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(50) "3;RELOJ DEPORTIVO CON GPS GARMIN INSTINCT SOLAR AM"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(42) "6;RELOJ DEPORTIVO CON GPS GARMIN FORERUNNE"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(42) "8;PORT�TIL ASUS ROG STRIX G15 G512LW-HN069"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(40) "9;PORT�TIL ASUS ROG ZEPHYRUS G14 GA401IU"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(26) "10;LAS TINIEBLAS Y EL ALBA"
```

Como veis, me mete los campos en el primer array, y hay un registro que no sé por qué no me lo lee bien y me lo divide en dos (Con esto arreglado, me sigue mostrando lo mismo en idnoencontrados). Pero aún así, que me muestro en idnoencontrados en todos un 1 de true... Tampoco veo que se pueda explicar por esto.

Muchas gracias, saludos.

Comment: tu logica del proceso no es correcta... en que momento reinicias el archivo? veo que lees hasta el final por cada fila de tu query.. pero nunca volves al principio...

Comment: ¿Por qué hay que volver al principio? ¿No es suficiente con leer el fichero CSV una vez?

Comment: si vos queres ver si todo lo que esta en tu base de datos esta en el archivo, por cada fila de tu base de datos, tenes que revisar todo el contenido del archivo... si solo lo haces con la primer fila, el resto de las filas no se compara contra nada.. ademas, tu if dentro de la comparacion esta mal.. si lo encuentra, dice lo encontre, pero por cada uno no encontrado, lo guarda en el array... cuando vos queres guardarlo si no esta en todo el archivo. Aca, esta mal toda la logica del proceso.. te recomendaria que vuelvas al papel y armes la logica como corresponde...